# How to convert text to xml with python?

Tags: xml, text

I want to convert a text file to xml file with python or Java,

my text:

> "café is a place, café has an address and opening hours"

my goal is to generate a file xml describe all the entities in the text

Comment: Please use an example in English if possible, like maybe: "_café is a place, café has an address and opening hours._"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest you googling your question before you start here a new question. You basically want to read text from a `*.txt` file and save text in a new `*.xml` file. Trust me there are quite many solutions out there. If you are stuck, come back here and we surely want to help you out. Good luck! :)

Comment: You want to convert free structure text to XML fixed structure? Way too broad.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, share your code which you've being trying to use for your task so far. Also, which language at the end you are going to use - Java, or python?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a little bit more specific regarding your goal with the xml, to get the best help with your question. You can interpret it in many ways, leaving many possible solutions to be discussed.

- Do you want to have a piece of code that always converts .txt to .xml? (hard)
- Do you only want to convert this single line, and would that be fine? (easy)
- Are you looking for an option in for example Jdeveloper to upload .txt and change it to .xml for further processing (easy but specific).

For whatever purpose you are looking an answer, the way text is structured in the .txt file is very important. If it is structured like a sentence (as it is in your example), it is going to be dificult to write a pice of generalized code for it. If it however resembles something like this, or if you can prepare the .txt file in a way looking like this:

```
1: 
Make········Model····Year····Mileage
2: 
BMW·········R1150RS··2004····14274··
3: 
Kawasaki····GPz1100··1996····60234··
```

Then it is actually going to be fairly easy. Converting formats is usually a matter of adjusting your data structure.
Above example I have taken from the following question on Quora. I'm sure the link is very helpfull to your cause!

[Wall of text on .txt to .xml on quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-convert-a-txt-file-to-a-xml-file)

Good luck with your goal!

Jesper

***Edit:*** as a reaction to your comment. Actually strings are hard to convert into tables, unless the strings always contain certain characteristics. "café is a place, café has an address and opening hours" is very general indeed. If the next sentence would be: "Pool is a place, Pool has an address and opening hours". You could write a substring function (http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_substring.html, for substrings in xslt), that takes a sentence and strips it of its usable information that comes after recurring entities in the string. However, it would be highly preferable to use my example above, and format your .txt data in a fashion that is easier to convert than a sentence, like comma seperated file.

```
Cafe, Pool, Library, School, Gym, Work,
Place, Adress, Opening Hours,
```

Comment: thanks Jesper,my general purpose is to extract the database tables from a text file (specifications) or to generate the entities of my database: the names of classes, the attributes, I know that it is quite difficult, for that I try to start with a simple sentence that respects a model and transform it into XML, after I will generalize little by little

Comment: okey thank you a lot ms. Jesper, i know that is very hard to analyse the unstructured  datas, for that i will do some pretreatment to my text, to make it simple as i can,

Comment: please if u have some power documentation about NLP or text analysis, share it with me ,thanks